# i want the count of each name on the list

Tags: python, list

```
zoo_animals = [ ]
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
for name  in zoo_animals:
    print("The number ",zoo_animals.count(name)," in the list is ",name)
```

**it gives me:**

[image]

```
The number  1  in the list is  Dog
The number  1  in the list is  cat
The number  1  in the list is  fish
The number  1  in the list is  shark
```

**What i wanted**

```
The number  1  in the list is  Dog
The number  2  in the list is  cat
The number  3  in the list is  fish
The number  4  in the list is  shark
```

Comment: [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) counts the number of occurrences of the given value. Check out [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). `for idx, name  in enumerate(zoo_animals, 1): print(f"the number {idx} in the list is {name}")`

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) (though thanks for also providing a transcript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for the count function, it explains what it does - counts the occurrences of the parameter in the list.

You want the **position / index** of each item, not the count

```
for idx, name in enumerate(zoo_animals): 
    print(f"the animal at position {idx+1} in the list is {name}")
```

Comment: Yes bro i never knew that we can use {} for writing a variable thank you.

Comment: It's called an f-string and only available from Python 3.8+ (i think)

Comment: Sir why you wrote the f before "" print( f " ")

Comment: @OneCricketeer, it was 3.6+ (i had to look it up too...)

Comment: @theredaait this is called a _f-string_ (formatting). Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498

Answer (score 0):

`List.count(item)` returns how many times it appears in the list, not where. You're looking for `List.index(item)` (but this is 0-based, as in the first item has an index of 0 and the second item has an index of 1, so you will want to add 1 to this)

Comment: Thank you i actually noticed this !

Comment: The `index` function always finds the first instance, so it will not work correctly if you have duplicates, and traversing the list repeatedly to find where you are when you should already know is wasteful and inelegant.

Comment: Yes, just I didn't want to recommend enumerate incase it confused them. Probably should have mentioned it in my answer though

Answer (score 0):

Oh I actually found it is there something better?

```
zoo_animals = [ ]
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
for name  in zoo_animals:
    print("The number ", zoo_animals.index(name)+1 ," in the list is ",name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The count method of list returns the frequency or the number of times the provided elements has occurred in the list.

Using enumerate, we get the element and the index of it simultaneously.

```
zoo_animals = [ ]

zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))

for i, name in enumerate(zoo_animals):
    print("The number ", i + 1," in the list is ",name)
```

Output:

```
Enter an animal = aa
Enter an animal = bb
Enter an animal = cc
Enter an animal = dd
The number  1  in the list is  aa
The number  2  in the list is  bb
The number  3  in the list is  cc
The number  4  in the list is  dd
```

Check the below links, to know more about enumerate(<-list name->) function

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/enumerate.html

Regards,

Comment: Thank you very very much,

Comment: Anytime buddy 

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `zoo_animals.count(name)` gives the count of distinct elements in the list and not the index. You could do this instead.

```
for i in range(len(zoo_animals)):
    print("The number {}  in the list is {}".format(i+1,zoo_animals[i]))
```

**Output**

```
The number 1  in the list is dog
The number 2  in the list is cat
The number 3  in the list is fish
The number 4  in the list is shark
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zoo_animals = [ ]
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
zoo_animals.append(input("Enter an animal = "))
for name in zoo_animals:
    print("The number ",zoo_animals.index(name) + 1," in the list is ",name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).